# error loading module '(' expected near '='

Tags: lua, coronasdk

This code is to create function listeners for the cannon shooting. When i run the code, it gave me an error Question1.lua:43 '('expected near '='

```
function cannonCharge = function(event)
  if(event.phase == 'began') then
        impulse = 0
        cannon.isVisible = true
        Runtime:addEventListener('enterFrame', charge)
        print ('cannonCharge')
    end
end

function shot = function(event)
    if(event.phase == 'ended') then

        Runtime:removeEventListener('enterFrame', charge)
        cannon.isVisible = true
        cannon.rotation = 0

        cannonBall = display.newImage('cannon ball.png', 84, 220)
        physics.addBody(cannonBall, {density = 1, friction = 0, bounce = 0})
        cannonBalls:insert(cannonBall)
        print ('shot')

-- Shoot cannon ball
cannonBall:applyLinearImpulse(3, impulse, cannonBall.x, cannonBall.y )

--Collision listener
cannonBall:addEventListener ('collision', ballCollision)

    end
end

function scene:createScene(event)
...
```

I added the listeners to enterScene

```
function scene:enterScene( event )
local group = self.view
background:addEventListener('touch', cannonCharge)
background:addEventListener('touch', shot) 
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

Variables don't have types; Only values do. So, instead of

```
function shot = function(event)
-- ...
end
```

Try

```
local shot = function(event)
-- ...
end
```

If you don't put `local`, the variable will be global. Use of globals should be minimized.

If you prefer a more structured syntax, you can use:

```
local function shot(event)
-- ...
end
```

That's equivalent to:

```
local shot
shot = function(event)
-- ...
end
```

Comment: I changed both cannonCharge and shot to local but it gave me an error, 'assertion failed'.

Comment: That's good. You've gotten over your syntax errors. Now you have a new question. The current question doesn't have enough detail for the new issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can not assign two touch listener on the same object. Because it's create conflict to which function it's call first.
instead of that, you need to assign one touch and one tap listener. So there is no conflict.
background:addEventListener('tap', cannonCharge)
background:addEventListener('touch', shot)

Comment: If i don't use touch for cannonCharge, the cannon will not rotate and just shoot forward. Switching them will give me the error assertion failed.

Comment: You can rotate your cannon in enterFrame or Runtime listener.

Comment: Can you let me know at which point you are getting  '('expected near '=' this error. I am unable to find line 43.